# ASP.NET Script Bundling returns bundled files but with 404 response code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, http-status-code-404

I have an c# ASP.NET web application. I have enabled JS bundling and everything seems to be configured (I have also checked a lot of stackoverflow similiar errors)

If I put the JS bundled file URL in a browser I get a response with all the JS files together and optimized but the http response code is 404, so when I use the url with script tag in my html page, the 404 response code avoid the web loadoing the JS file.

Has someone faced something similar?

Regards.

Comment: where do you see the 404? Chrome Dev tools, fiddler ?? This doesn't looks like it is possible.

Comment: Yes, using Chrome Dev Tools. Finally I have discover the problem: I am using a library for developing web portal (Microsoft Adx Studio) for Microsoft Dynamics and one of the modules (PortalRoutingModel) was intercepting the request and returning 404.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally discover the problem.

I am using a library for developing web portal (Microsoft Adx Studio) for Microsoft Dynamics and one of the modules (PortalRoutingModule) was intercepting the requests and returning 404 for bundling urls

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, were you able to get bundling to work within the adx portal?

Comment: Like usual, the second you ask a question you figure out the answer. The RegisterRoutes method in our portal project is set to ignore routes of js/{resource}.bundle.js" The bundle we were trying to use wasn't of this pattern and was getting routed as a 404 as a result. After changing the bundle to match the ignored route pattern it worked.